# JavaScriptEngineSwitcher xml namespace missing

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, xml-namespaces, uglifyjs

I recently was trying to get UglifyJs to work and installed three related Nuget packages:
JavaScriptEngineSwitcher Core
JavaScriptEngineSwitcher MsieJsEngine
JavaScriptEngineSwitcher V8JsEngine

I then had this node in my web.config:

```
<jsEngineSwitcher xmlns="http://tempuri.org/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Configuration.xsd">
<core>
  <engines>
    <add name="V8JsEngine" type="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.V8JsEngine, JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8" />
    <add name="MsieJsEngine" type="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie.MsieJsEngine, JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie" />
  </engines>
</core>
</jsEngineSwitcher>
```

However when I build I get quite a few messages regarding the xml namespace mentioned in that node:

> Message   2   Could not find schema information for the element 'http://tempuri.org/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Configuration.xsd:jsEngineSwitcher'. 
>   Message 3   Could not find schema information for the element 'http://tempuri.org/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Configuration.xsd:core'. 
>   Message 4   Could not find schema information for the element 'http://tempuri.org/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Configuration.xsd:engines'.
>   Message 5   Could not find schema information for the element 'http://tempuri.org/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Configuration.xsd:add'.

I tried going to the url for the namespace, but it just redirects me to Bing.com.  Is there a new url this xml namespace should point at?

Answer (score 2):

Install the [JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ConfigurationIntelliSense](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ConfigurationIntelliSense/) package in one project of solution (e.g. web application project).